# How to do geo spatial searching in plain mysql

Tags: mysql, geolocation, query-optimization

Given a bounding box of `southwest(lng, lat)` and `northeast(lng,lat)`, I want to find out all points that falls within this given region.   The table is currently designed as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS steps (
   id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   rid int NOT NULL COMMENT 'route ID',
   seq int NOT NULL COMMENT 'sequence',
   longitude decimal(10,7) NOT NULL,
   latitude decimal(10,7) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

My question is: how to let mysql search **faster**.   So,

1. Since mysql only uses one index per query, so it seems not efficient to simply add index for `latitude` and `longitude`?
2. I cannot use MySQL Geo Spatial Extension, any solution must be native MySQL.
3. Since the app is to display "routes" within the view port, it is necessary to get points adjucent to, but outside of, the given viewport.
4. Will it help to use a solution such as geohash?  If so, how can I adapt the proper length of geohash in relation to the given viewport?

**EDIT**

1. I cannot use geo-spatial feature of MySQL, as the app runs on a MySQL 5.7, which I do not have administrative right, even I could arrange to add this extension (if 5.7 support it), it is not favorable to us because we do not want to introduce any incompatibility to other part of our system.
2. The application is to show "historical" routes which are highly "clustered" i.e, as time goes by, there may be a **lot** of close-together routes, in several sites, each sites may occupy e.g. 1k~2k square kilometers.  So, apart from what I already asked, another question might be: **how to eliminate closed-together routes, if some are mostly covered up by other routes**.

Comment: Spatial indexes have been added because it is hard to index with the previously existing indexes (and thus the indexes you have to limit yourself to). Depending on your data, you may be able to implement a simple, manual version of what spatial indexes do: precategorize your points to appropriate regions, and then, if your bounding box e.g. lies in france, you can neglect all points you prelabeled as not being in france.

Comment: Is a "route" an ordered list of lat/lng points?  What is the metric to judge whether two routes are "close-together"?  Can two "close" routes have a different number of "points"?

Comment: 5.7.1 InnoDB DATA_GEOMETRY (SPATIAL)
5.7.5 ADD SPATIAL INDEX(geom)
5.7.6 SPATIAL: ST_Distance_Sphere() and ST_MakeEnvelope()
Perhaps you need the spherical SRS instead of planar; I think that does not come until 8.0.

Comment: And what area of the globe are you working with?  If it is a small enough area, a suitable projection could treat it as flat.

Comment: @RickJames the criteria to judge two routes are close-together is the tricky part.  The purpose is to return as few points to the frontend as possible, and the criteria is that if two lines are **visually** indistinguishable to the eye on google map, then they are "close together". i.e. it is related to the zoom of map and the resolution of display...

Comment: @xrfang - are the routes typically close to a straight line?  Are you comparing a thousand routes to see which ones are similar?  Or comparing just two?

Comment: @RickJames lines are not straight, they have a timestamp attached. I would like to eliminate routes (not sending them to frontend) if later lines overlaps them.  This is purely for performance reason.   Apart from that, I do not need to know similarity of routes.  The scale may be a few thousand routes on one site, and they have typically 1-2k steps per route, after applying DouglasPeucker algorithm

Comment: Is the bounding box to decide which "routes" fit inside the box?  Is the box the screen?  Are we looking at a few km (miles)?  (I'm still trying to wrap my head around what direction this project is going -- then pondering algorithms and techniques.)  Douglas-Peucker seems straighforward.

Comment: @RickJames yes, the bounding box is the screen. the box could cover several km to, e.g. 1/3 of earth.  Route elimination may not be needed at all. But in order to handle unexpected large amount of data, if it is not complex to do the elimination, it will make my algorithm more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

I redesigned the table after studied Rick and O.Jone's answer.  Here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE `steps` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rid` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'route ID',
  `seq` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'step sequence',
  `scale` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'dp bitmask',
  `longitude` decimal(10,7) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(10,7) NOT NULL,
  `grid` mediumint NOT NULL COMMENT 'grid number',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ridseq` (`rid`,`seq`),
  KEY `filter` (`scale`,`grid`,`longitude`,`latitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

The "tricks" are **grid** and **scale**, where `grid` is a simple partition scheme, I just divide the globe into 256 sections along both longitude and altitude. and use a `uint16` to record a given point's grid #, where the 1st byte is longitude, and 2nd byte is latitude.

And the scale is a one byte value used as a bitmask, which maps to different "zoom level" of a map view.   The mapping relation is designed as:

```
DouglasPeucker Threshold    Zoom Level
0.00005                     16
0.0001                      15,14
0.0004                      13,12
0.0008                      11,10
0.002                       9,8
0.008                       7
0.016                       6
0.032                       5
```

The start and end of route always have `scale=0xFF`, other points will have relevant bit set to 1 if it appears on that zoom level.

Given the above table schema, and three input arguments: `zoom-level`, `south-west` and `northeast` I may use the following query:

```
SELECT rid,seq,longitude,latitude FROM steps WHERE 
  ((grid>=... AND grid<=...) OR (...)) //grid filter
  AND scale>=..                        //zoom level filter
  AND longitude BETWEEN .. AND ..
  AND latitude BETWEEN .. AND ..       //view port filter
ORDER BY rid,seq
```

I hope this query could utilize the index on this table. **EXPLAIN** shows:

- possible_key: filter
- key: NULL
- rows: 3783
- filtered: 0.07
- extra: Using where; Using filesort

If I remove the `ORDER BY`, `Using filesort` will disappear.   I wonder if that will slow down query or not, i.e. shall I query the data and sort it in my application instead of mysql?

Comments are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your query efficiency will come from an index on just `(longitude)` or just `(latitude)`.  But a [compound index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on both `(latitude, longitude)` will make things a little faster. Why? MySQL can retrieve the second coordinate value, which it must also check against your boundaries, directly from the index without looking it up in the table. That saves time and IO in your MySQL server.

Unless your table is vast, or your bounding boxes are really big, or you have some other application performance issue, this will work tolerably well. If it doesn't you probably should start using the geospatial extension.

What else will help?

1. Changing the data type of your latitude and longitude from DECIMAL to FLOAT (single precision). GPS data can be adequately represented by single-precision floating point, and the comparisons and arithmetic are slightly faster.  (If your data are more precise than FLOAT allows, surely you know about your geodetic datum and the projection you use.)
2. If your data points are spread out mostly east-to-west (USA for example) use an index on `(longitude, latitude)` because longitude is more selective.  If they are spread out mostly north-to-south (Japan for example) reverse the order of the columns in the index: latitude is more selective.
3. Make your compound index match your query. If your query looks like this

   ```sql
   SELECT rid, seq, latitude, longitude
     FROM steps
    WHERE rid = ###constant##
      AND latitude BETWEEN ###southboundary### AND ###northboundary###
      AND longitude BETWEEN ###westboundar### AND ###eastboundary###
    ORDER BY seq
   ```

   your best choice of [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) is `(rid, latitude, longitude, seq)`.

I think your requirement is to get all the routes that pass through your bounding box. That you can do with this query.

```
SELECT rid, seq, latitude, longitude
  FROM steps
 WHERE rid IN (
      SELECT rid
        FROM steps
       WHERE latitude BETWEEN ###southboundary### AND ###northboundary###
       AND longitude BETWEEN ###westboundar### AND ###eastboundary###
)
ORDER BY rid, seq
```

A good covering index for the subquery will be `(latitude, longitude, rid)`.

How well will this scale up? If your bounding boxes are small compared to the range of lat/long values in your table it will scale up quite well: BETWEEN filters on indexed columns are a highly optimized range-scan use case.  It is difficult to say 100k rows or 10m rows without knowing a lot more about your application. You should read https://use-the-index-luke.com by Marcus Winand to learn more about the wizardry of indexing.

Comment: According to your experience, what amount of points will your solution handle with decent performance, assuming I am using an "adequate" ec instance on AWS? Thanks.

Comment: Please see my edit at the end of my answer.

Comment: I found that the Optimizer will pick between `INDEX(lat, lng)` and `INDEX(lng, lat)`.  Chile makes a good N-S example!

Comment: In the last example, beware of inefficient optimization of `IN (SELECT ...)`.  That example easily converts to a `JOIN (SELECT rid...)`, but then needs the addition of `INDEX(rid)`.

Comment: @xrfang - I have a comparison here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql#comparison_of_methods -- a simple bounding-box took about 24ms to search for the 10 nearest cities (limited to 50 miles) out of 3.1M on earth.  This compares to 40sec for no index 15ms for Spatial, 3ms for Z-order and 2ms for partitioning.  Fast enough?  (Computer CPUs have not changed much since 2000, so my speeds are probably close for AWS.)

Comment: @RickJames what is Z-order and partitioning? Is Z-order related to geohash? as in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve

Comment: @xrfang - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash has similar drawings and colors.  My blog above has links to implementations of Partitioning and Z-order.  And there is a pure-PHP GreatCircleDistance.

Comment: correction -- pure MySQL GCD.

Answer (score 0):

Have these:

```
INDEX(lat, lng),
INDEX(lng, lat)
```

And `DROP` these if you have them:  `INDEX(lat)`, `INDEX(lng)`; they get in the way.

The Optimizer will use either of those 2-column indexes, depending which one *seems* to have fewer rows in the E-W or N-S stripe of the globe.

Why can you not use `SPATIAL` indexing?  It is available in 8.0.

Here is a thorough discussion of the problem of "find nearest" in MySQL.  It includes a discussion of precision needed for lat/lng.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

That also goes into algorithms that are faster than a simple bounding box.

My blog goes into "Z-order" indexing, which works something like gohash.  I have looked into using a Hilbert space-filling curve, too.  That promises to have similar performance to the Z-order, but with quite different code.

The partitioning and Z-order solutions hit "not many more" items than are needed in the resultset.  The 2-column indexes hit a lot more items since they cover a whole stripe of latitude (or longitude).

What does your `SELECT` look like?

As for variable length of geohash, I doubt it.  I looked into that for Z-order and concluded that I needed more than 32 bits and not more than 64.  Otherwise, the algorithm will falsely place some items inside or outside the bounding box.

A Spatial `POINT` takes a bulky 25 bytes (compared to 12 for your pair of Decimals and some smaller representations mentioned in my blog.)  But I don't see why you could not have used Point.  For vehicles, I would pick `FLOAT` (8 bytes, 1.7 m / 5.6 ft resolution).  For persons: `DECIMAL(8,6)/(9,6)` (9 bytes, 16cm / 1/2 ft).

Comment: I explained why I cannot use spatial-indexing, and added some details about my application.  Also I read your blog on find-nearest, I feel that my requirement may be easier (i.e. computationally cheaper) than yours?